# Nop Commerce - Map custom stored procedure to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I am using nop commerce 3.4, (it uses EF - Code First) and I would like to map a stored procedure that executes a select, to a custom entity.
I have created the custom entity (CategoryItemModel) to map to in the Domain.
But when NopObjectContext runs calling the stored proc i get the error:
The entity type CategoryItemModel is not part of the model for the current context.
How do I add my CategoryItemModel to the context?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you written the mapping? Here's an example of a mapping for Product entity.

```
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog;

namespace Nop.Data.Mapping.Catalog
{
    public partial class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public ProductMap()
        {
            this.ToTable("Product");
            this.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            this.Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(400);
            this.Property(p => p.MetaKeywords).HasMaxLength(400);

            /* ... other mappings ... */
            /* ... refer 'Product.cs' ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @wooncherk, I am trying to map to a select stored procedure. If I add the above mapping, it will try to create a table instead of map a sproc wouldn't it?

Comment: Mapping is to tell EF now to link a DB table to code, you need it no matter you are using an sproc (or LINQ) to SELECT. :)

Comment: Thanks @wooncherk. The problem is my select is a custom entity- not mapped exactly to a table schema. So what do I map it to in that case? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Custom entity? So you do not have any table that you are selecting from? How is that possible? :)

Comment: As long as you have a DB table (can be your own, non-standard in nopCommerce), you need to have a domain model as well as a mapping. Then only EF can do the rest. :)

Comment: Sorry @wooncherk, it is selecting fields from a table - but also includes fields from other tables. So I ment that the SPROC doesnt map exactly to a table schema - there are different fields in the sproc from other tables. But ill attempt to attach it to the "Categories" table. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @wooncherk, I get this error attempting to map my sproc to a table:
The entity types 'CategoryMenu' and 'Category' cannot share table 'Categories' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expected solution like below, I know it's late. But I added this for future references.

This only works nopCommers < 4.0

```
private List<ElasticStoreMapping> GetStoreMappingsForProducts(int[] productIds)
{
   var pProductIds = _dataProvider.GetParameter();
   pProductIds.ParameterName = "ProductIds";
   pProductIds.Value = productIds == null ? string.Empty : string.Join(",", productIds);
   pProductIds.DbType = DbType.String;

   return _dbContext.SqlQuery<ElasticStoreMapping>($"Exec GetStoreMappingForElastic @ProductIds", pProductIds).ToList();
}
```